# Why wrap a new object in parentheses before accessing one of its members?

Tags: javascript

I did read that this

```
var time = (new Date()).getTime();
```

is preferred to this

```
var time = new Date().getTime();
```

although the result in both examples is the same. What is the reason why I should wrap a new object in parentheses before accessing any of its members?

Comment: It works both ways, don't worry about it. Not using parens is very common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's clearer to read.

You could also have written `(new Date).getTime()`, which is definitely different from `new Date.getTime()` (which has the meaning `new (Date.getTime)()`). Of course, if you know the precendence rules the parentheses are meaningless to *you*, but the code is still more explicit and better to maintain.